# following type of exception occur java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

[Otp Genration button code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LO4X.png)
[Otp verify button code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hzQh.png)

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.learning, PID: 30231
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof, sessionInfo, temporary proof, or enrollment ID.

I have tried so many solutions, but nothing works.whenever i run the application ,it was send otp but it can not verify otp in application

Comment: Try to add SHA1 and SHA256 in firebase project app setting.

Comment: Is your app in production?

Comment: When adding code to a question, please don't use a screenshot of it and add it as a code snippet.